# Timing out tracking pixels in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, webkit

I have a javascript that creates several div elements and inside them an img tag for each of several image urls. I also have a timeout function that after a period is supposed to cause the image to stop loading. In FF this can be achieved by setting the img tag's src attribute to be blank. In webkit browsers it's a different story since all requests are made asynchronously.

The code I have so far looks similar to this:

```
function tag(url_array, timeout)
{
    var _tag_div = document.getElementById('tag_div');

    for(var i in url_array)
    {
        var e = document.createElement('div');
        e.setAttribute('id', '_tag_' + i);
        e.innerHTML = '<img src="' + urls[i] + '"/>';
        _tag_div.appendChild(e);

        setTimeout(blank_img.bind(window, i), timeout);

    }

    function blank_img(x)
    {
        document.getElementById('_tag_' + x).firstChild.src = '';
    }

}
```

As I said this works well in FF but in webkit browsers it does nothing to stop the loading of the images. Given that this is going to be used for a pixel tracking system on 3rd party pages the code needs to be as lightweight as possible. Does anybody know of a solution to this problem or can maybe assist me in finding one? Thanks in advance,
-CarbonX

Comment: Can't you just let the server track the actual webpage request instead of nasty pixels?

Comment: haha, I wish... sadly these are not our organizations pixels, they're piggybacking on our system.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing them from the DOM completely with `removeChild`, e.g.:

```
function blank_img(x) { 
    var imgTag = document.getElementById('_tag_' + x);
    if(imgTag) { imgTag.parentNode.removeChild(imgTag); }
}
```

I'm assuming you don't need the tags later...

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't do anything to stop the request either. Thanks for trying though.